# Cancel Prompt doesn't return desired outcome

Tags: javascript

I've setup a simple javascript program that returns the number of characters you input, however, when the value is null I want an error message to display. All works fine except when I cancel the prompt and the console gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" and doesn't display the error message in the else statement. Here is the code:

```js
let message = prompt("What would you like to express today?");
let msgLength = message.length
let number =  180 - msgLength;

if (message) {

  let input = `Your character count is: ${msgLength} || You have ${number} characters left.`;
  let displayMsg = `"${message}"`

  document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = displayMsg;
  document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML = input;
} else {

  let error = `Please enter a valid message.`;
  document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = error;
}
```

Comment: move these `let msgLength = message.length; let number =  180 - msgLength;` inside your if statement. Null doesnt have a length so calling `message.length` is triggering your error when there is no message

Answer (score 0):

Prompt returns either the `string` entered or `null`. When user cancel the prompt, it returns null and that's why the error shows that it cannot read property `length` of `null`. Access this length property only inside the `if(message) {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check the length of message [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) `prompt` returns:

> A string containing the text entered by the user, or null.

To solve this problem you need to move `let msgLength = message.length` inside your if statement,